# Leaflet: How to add multiple markers onto featureGroup

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markers

I am trying to do something like : https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim/blob/master/demo-group.gif 
where I have multiple markers.

In the example code https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim/blob/master/demo-group.html 
each location has been manually added using

```
     var trd = [63.5, 11],
        mad = [40.5, -3.5],
        lnd = [51.5, -0.5],
        ams = [52.3, 4.75],
        vlc = [39.5, -0.5];

     var route = L.featureGroup([
        L.marker(trd),
        L.polyline([trd, ams]),
        L.marker(ams),
        L.polyline([ams, lnd]),
        L.marker(lnd),
        L.polyline([lnd, mad]),
        L.marker(mad),
        L.polyline([mad, vlc]),
        L.marker(vlc)
    ]);
```

My question is, if I have many markers (e.g. 500 markers), how can I create the route without manually adding each marker and polyline to the L.featureGroup.

```
   var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds();
   for (var i = 0; i < mTool.length; i++) {
            var loc = new L.LatLng(mTool[i].lat, mTool[i].lon);
            bounds.extend(loc);
            var marker = new L.Marker(loc);
            map.addLayer(marker);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: What you want to do is provided by the same [github project of IvanSanchez](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim). Please read [demo.html](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim/blob/master/demo.html) instead of demo-group.html

This is easily done by looping through an array of markers, as you rightly hinted at it. The code could be as below:

```
var markers = [[63.5, 11],
        [40.5, -3.5],
        [51.5, -0.5],
        [52.3, 4.75],
        [39.5, -0.5]];

var route = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

var n = markers.length;

for (var i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            var marker = new L.Marker(markers[i]);
            var line = new L.polyline([markers[i],markers[i+1]]);
            route.addLayer(marker);
            route.addLayer(line);
};
route.addLayer(new L.Marker(markers[n-1]));

map.fitBounds(route.getBounds());
```

I created a working example on gist ([here](https://bl.ocks.org/phvaillant/2624985a31b056102abd1564aadd68f9)).

Comment: I am wondering if each marker can show its popup base on the polyline touch the marker.

Comment: Yes, just play with the [`popupAnchor`](http://www.leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#icon-popupanchor) option of the marker's icon.

Comment: Thank you, I am too new to this stuff. ^^

Comment: I am trying to do like:

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            var marker = new L.Marker(markers[i]);
            var line = new L.polyline([markers[i],markers[i+1]]);
            route.addLayer(marker);
            route.addLayer(line);
};
route.addLayer(new L.Marker(markers[n-1]));

Comment: I am trying to put the code marker.bindPopup("POPUP").openPopup();  but the popup doesnt open automatically when snakein is running.

Comment: You can imagine something like that (https://bl.ocks.org/phvaillant/f793c2519739134afb6ef69dd4e82091), but please bear in mind that 1) one asks precise questions on stackoverflow 2) one tried to solve the issue him/herself first and has undertaken extensive search. Don't post on the same stackoverflow to ask about lots of additional features for your project. Your questions have quite drifted from your initial question. Asking for popup support of the snake plugin is a great question though, and maybe Ivan Sanchez has already dealt with that problem and provided a work around!